# Assigning values to an array in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to change a value of an array in VBA, but is happening the Run-time error '13' Type mismatch
What I try to do is to open an user form where are 6 buttons, when the first 5 buttons are pressed, the 6th will be enabled

```
Public I As Integer
Public Botones As Variant

Sub funcion_final()
Botones = Array(False, False, False, False)
MainFrame.Show
End Sub

Function ChangeValue(I)
Botones(I) = True //Here is the error
End Function
```

And here the code of the buttons, all have exactly the same code, just changing the number that is sent as parameter

```
Private Sub BPieza_1_Click()
ChangeValue 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you ever call `funcion_final`?

Comment: Well I just have closed it, reset my pc and executed again and it works No idea why.... but well, it's working Thanks a lot

Sorry for make lose your time

Comment: It should be `Sub ChangeValue(I)` and not function. You are not returning anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`funcion_final()` is never being called, so the array is never initialized. Before calling `ChangeValue()` make sure that you call `funcion_final()`.